# Rsyslog conditionally raise severity with filemonitoring not working

Tags: syslog, rsyslog

The following rsyslog configuration is used to monitor the apache access file.

```
# Apache access file:
$InputFileName /var/log/apache2/access.log
$InputFileTag apache-access:
$InputFileStateFile stat-apache-access
#$InputFileSeverity info  //This is commented because I wanted to set this based on condition.
$InputFilePersistStateInterval 20000
$InputRunFileMonitor

if $programname == "apache-access" then {
    if ($msg contains " 500 ") then $InputFileSeverity 'error';
    action(type="ommysql" server="127.0.0.1" serverport="3306" db="Syslog" uid="rsyslog" pwd="somepasswd")
    stop
}
```

This was tested with a php code that uses `header("HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error")`

and used `curl -I localhost/phpinfo.php` which returned a 500.

However, rsyslog is logging it as `Severity NOTICE`. The facility which it recorded was `LOCAL0`.

I was looking to change the severity to `Error` if there is a `500` in the message, which is not working as expected, and logs as Notice.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to figure out.

```
# Apache access file:
$InputFileName /var/log/apache2/access.log
$InputFileTag apache-access:
$InputFileStateFile stat-apache-access
#$InputFileSeverity crit
$InputFilePersistStateInterval 20000

if $programname == "apache-access" then {
    #if ($msg contains " 500 ") then  $InputFileSeverity error 
    if ($msg contains " 500 ") then  $InputFileSeverity info
    action(type="ommysql" server="127.0.0.1" serverport="3306" db="Syslog" uid="rsyslog" pwd="somepasswd")
    stop
}


$InputRunFileMonitor
```

Put the `$InputRunFileMonitor` after the conditional, and it works.